# sha & md5 Collision if string length equal

Tags: md5, sha, sha512

I understand that md5 and sha512, etc... are insecure because they can have collisions.

However, is it still possible to have a collision if the string length is the same?

Ie. To authenticate, it would check length of password and that it matches say the md5 / sha password hash.

In other words, if I have the ten digit password:a123456789

Would any other 10 alpha/numeric/special character md5/sha hash collide and be the same?

If yes, would they still collide if they were only alpha numeric? And could you give an example?

All the collisions I have read of seem to be of two PDFS or similar, but that would tend to make sense. I would think if the input length being hashed was equal and less than 100 characters there should be no collisions I would assume.

Interested to hear thoughts on this.

Comment: That's a question that would be better asked on [security.se]

Answer (score 0):

*If* a hash is insecure because it can have collisions, then *all* hashes are insecure. Any hash is guaranteed to have collisions by the pigeonhole principle, when the length of data being hashed is greater than the length of the hash output.

If you are asking, then, by limiting the size of the data so that it does not exceed the hash, does this mean there will be no collisions? I think that would be depending on the hash algorithm. Consider a hash that simply adds the values of each byte of data together, into an arbitrary sized integer that can have as many bits as the length of the input data. Certainly, there will be data sequences which when added together, arrive at the same hash value, despite the data length not exceeding the hash length.

It's not the lack of collisions that makes the hash secure -- it is the very, very low likelihood that you can, given the desired hash, compute a value that would give that hash.

If you really want a hash that produces no collisions, then you can use encryption. Encrypting the input, and using the output as if it were a hash, would give you zero collisions.

Comment: Jim, thanks for the analysis, but that was not my question. My question is if I say the password must be 9 digits in length, can’t be longer can’t be shorter, will any other 9 digit strings equal the same hash. That is my question. This is not for passwords. I’m using it for other algorithms

Comment: So take the md5 hash for the input: “somestring”.

The md5 hash is:
1f129c42de5e4f043cbd88ff6360486f

The string is 10 digits long. So if I wanted to check it was valid my parameters would be if md5(“somestring”) = 1f129c42de5e4f043cbd88ff6360486f AND string length = 10, then authenticate string. Else it is not authenticated.

However, this only works if no other string that is 10 characters long equals the md5 hash of:
1f129c42de5e4f043cbd88ff6360486f

Which is my question. Can strings of the same length collide with md5 or sha?

Comment: Yes, certainly strings of the same length could hash to the same value. But with a strong hash algorithm, you would likely never find them. I would say, checking the length adds nothing to the strength of security. Just be sure to use cryptographic-strength hashes.